# Bash script for reads from csv and use it in mysql query

Tags: mysql, bash, csv

I need a bash script which reads from csv 2 values per line and use it in mysql query.

The .csv contains about +3k lines like this:

```
FA63MZ6,200000000163,2020-06-27,CF,Name Surname1 Surname1
FA63MZ6,200000000163,2020-06-27,CF,Name2 Surname2 Surname2
```

I would like to extract "date" and "Name Surname1 Surname1" as variables to use it in a mysql  query.

I am triying with :

```
echo "select status from invoices where date_created= \"${date01}\" and customer_id in (select id from customers where name = \"${name01}\" );" | mysql -u user -pPassword -D dbname | grep -v status
```

Ideally this script could be create a .csv with the result of query:

```
FA63MZ6,200000000163,2020-06-27,CF,Name Surname1 Surname1,paid
FA63MZ6,200000000164,2020-06-27,CF,Name2 Surname2 Surname2,not_paid
```

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work, however is untested:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read -r LINE; do
  DATE=$(awk -F, '{print $3}' <<< "${LINE}")
  NAME=$(awk -F, '{print $5}' <<< "${LINE}")
  RES=$(echo "select status from invoices where date_created= \"${DATE}\" and customer_id in (select id from customers where name = \"${NAME}\" );" | mysql -u user -pPassword -D dbname | grep -v status)
 echo "$LINE, $RES"
done < "csv_file.csv"
```

It should be noted that it works only for provided format `FA63MZ6,200000000163,2020-06-27,CF,Name Surname1 Surname1` and does not work with quoted forms of csv, or fields containing `,`

Comment: If `LINE` is an array, `${LINE}` is the first element of it. And if you want `read` to split on commas, set `IFS` appropriately. Useless Use Of Cat (tm) too.

Comment: I want to read the whole LINE from a file with default IFS (newline, tab, space), extract arguments for query with awk and put it back. I honestly don't understand what you really mean and what arrays could come from provided format `FA63MZ6,200000000163,2020-06-27,CF,Name Surname1 Surname1`

Comment: Thanks @user1452962, the script return : " FACE63MZ6,200000000163,2020-06-27,CF,Maycol, " when must be returns: "FACE63MZ6,200000000163,2020-06-27,CF,Maycol Adolfo Test
,paid" . I mean $NAME has only a name.

Comment: If you don't want `read` to split the line into an array, why are you using `-a` with it?

Comment: ok, this is the key, I have removed -a from while and now seems to works.

Comment: Why `< <(cat "csv_file.csv")` and not just `< csv_file.csv` ???

Comment: `@Shawn` ? No need two 'awk' to feed 2 variables

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
{
    while IFS=, read -r f1 f2 f3 f4 f5; do
        printf "SELECT status FROM invoice WHERE date_created=\047$f2\047 AND
        customer_id IN (
        SELECT id FROM customers WHERE name = \047$f5\047);"
        echo
    done < Input_File.csv
} | mysql --skip-column-names -u user -pPassword -D dbname
```

The `\047` ascii sequence is the single quote character.

---

## Test without MySQL

```
while IFS=, read -r f1 f2 f3 f4 f5; do
    printf "SELECT status FROM invoice WHERE date_created=\047$f2\047 AND
    customer_id IN (
    SELECT id FROM customers WHERE name = \047$f5\047);"
    echo
done < Input_File.csv
```

## Output

```
SELECT status FROM invoice WHERE date_created='200000000163' AND
    customer_id IN (
    SELECT id FROM customers WHERE name = 'Name Surname1 Surname1');
SELECT status FROM invoice WHERE date_created='200000000163' AND
    customer_id IN (
    SELECT id FROM customers WHERE name = 'Name2 Surname2 Surname2');
```

Comment: I'd use `mysql --skip-column-names` instead of the final grep

Comment: Now where's the `FA63MZ6,200000000163,2020-06-27,CF,Name Surname1 Surname1,paid` output? :)

Comment: Feeded to MySQL `STDIN`. If you remove ` | mysql ...........`, you will see the output of teh script

Comment: Added the output in my answer

Comment: @GillesQuenot your code works, but doesn't output in a csv format with `paid` or `not_paid`  :( Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: For this, we need a sample of the mysql output in you original post

Comment: And you have far more than a start here